# Colocar div com imagem sobre outra div

Tags: css

Estou tentando aplicar uma solução em uma div em meu projeto, mas não estou conseguindo, fiz um teste no JSFiddle deu certo, como pode ser visto aqui, pela minha limitação em css estou tendo dificuldade em implementar.

```css
.produtos-wrapper{
   position:relative;
}
.imagem-mascara {
   width:100px; /* largura da imagem máscara */
   height:68px; /* altura da imagem máscara */
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   background:url(http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/imagens/tag-lancamento.png) 0 0 no-repeat; /* imagem máscara */
}
```

```html
<div class="produtos-wrapper">
   <img src="http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/imagens/img.png" width="191" height="117" border="0" />
   <div class="imagem-mascara"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adventistapr/kkg6t6cy/)

E preciso aplicar no meu site nesse caso aqui:

[Página para exibição](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=2&sub=15)

Vejam que a imagem está no canto superior do site.

Comment: Tente utilizar seletores como :before ou :after no seu css, talvez ajudem, dê uma pesquisada e faça testes :) Dica: http://tableless.com.br/como-usar-before-after/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você esqueceu de colocar `position: relative;` na classe `.produtos-wrapper` do seu site.

```
.produtos-wrapper{
   position:relative;
}
```

Isso faz com que as divs com `position: absolute;` dentro de `.produtos-wrapper` fiquem com o posicionamento relativo à esta.

Está funcionando exatamente como seu exemplo no JSFiddle.

Comment: Muito bom... eu já estava pensando em readaptar pra usar com seletores :before... kkk, talvez seja meu modo de trabalhar mesmo que influencia na decisão ou meu pouco conhecimento de css também.

Comment: Olá @André Ribeiro, só mais uma dúvida, a imagem não sendo repetida como deveria, será que cometi alguma falha?

Comment: @adventistapr como assim repetida?

Comment: Olá @André Ribeiro, é que essas imagens estão dentro de um loop e não está repetindo, quando redimensiono o navegador ela aparece repetida.

Comment: @adventistapr Adicione `position:relative` também à sua classe `.produtos-conteudo`. Parece que resolve o problema.

Comment: Grande, super, hiper ajuda, valeu mesmo @André Ribeiro